# Removing jquery-rails from my Gemfile causes a error on bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I thought Bundler was supposed to handle all the dependencies so I should be able to remove and add Gems at will right? But when I remove jquery-rails from my Gemfile and try to run Bundle Update
I get a lot of errors and at the top it says:

```
Retrying dependency api due to error (2/3): Zlib::BufError buffer error
Retrying dependency api due to error (3/3): Zlib::BufError buffer error
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at
http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
```

If I add jquery-rails back in it works fine.

Comment: What are you passing to the source api?